# problem while using " yum groups "

Tags: centos, rhel, yum, rpm, man

When i am trying to use yum groups commands in RHEL 7 it is giving me following output.

```
#yum groups list
There is no installed groups file. 
Maybe run: yum groups mark convert (see man yum)
```

I have created my own repository and `gpgkey` is disabled for it.
All yum related commands are working except the yum groups command.

Comment: did you run "yum groups mark convert" ?

Comment: many solutions have been suggested in these related links: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28491548/fedora-no-installed-groups-file
https://access.redhat.com/discussions/1262603